# How to access servlet thorugh mobile

Tags: java

While deploying on simulator my app was working flawlessly.
Here is the piece of code i was using to make connection

```
URL u=new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/music.com/first");
URLConnection urlConnection=u.openConnection();
```

I was accessing servlet which is in the webapps folder of tomcat6.
But now i want to run app by deploying on original device which is connected to wifi and my system is also connected to internet.

The problem is, what should i write in place of ip address?

Comment: *what should I write in place of ip address?* Use the public URL for your site instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please will you elaborate the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to control panel and open network setting in that click on "Change adapter settings", Left click on network connection in pop up menu select "Status". Click on details here it will show the ip. At this point i had found that my IP is 192.168.1.2

And according to my code i had adjusted it so that i can access Servlet through Mobile

```
URL u=new URL("http://192.168.1.2:8080/music.com/first");
URLConnection urlConnection=u.openConnection();
```

The only mistake i was doing was, I had not included port number with IP. But as of now i got that.